# How to numerically solve PDE that governs the free vortex wake model?

Tags: pde, fluid-dynamics, numerics

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4187562) at Math SE</sub>

---

I am reading a paper on the free vortex wake model for a helicopter rotor blade, which is described by the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \psi} (\psi, \zeta) + \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \zeta} (\psi, \zeta) = \frac{1}{\Omega} \vec{V} \left( \vec{r}(\psi, \zeta), t\right)$$

where $\zeta$ is the wake age angle, and $\psi$ is the azimuthal blade location (both measured in radians).

Also, it is known that $d \psi=d t \times \Omega$, where $\Omega $ is a constant that refers to the rotational speed of a rotor blade (rad/s).$V$ refers to the velocity, and $ r(\psi ,\zeta )$ is the location of a Lagrangian marker.

Since it is a technical paper, it only gives a brief summary of the method used, and I really have no idea how I should write a code to solve for $ r(\psi ,\zeta )$ with $V$. The paper uses a predictor-corrector 2nd backward scheme as shown here ($\frac{\partial \vec{r}(\psi, \zeta)}{\partial \psi}$ is computed using a 2-step backward Euler's method and $\frac{\partial \vec{r}(\psi, \zeta)}{\partial \zeta}$ is computed using central difference) :

\begin{array}{r}
\vec{r}^{m}\left(\psi+\Delta \psi_{i}, \zeta+\Delta \zeta\right)= \\
\left\{\frac{\vec{V}}{\Omega}-\left(-\frac{1}{2 \Delta \zeta}+\frac{23}{\phi}\right) \vec{r}^{m}\left(\psi+\Delta \psi_{i}, \zeta\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2 \Delta \zeta}-\frac{21}{\phi}\right) \vec{r}^{m}(\psi, \zeta+\Delta \zeta)\right. \\
+\left(\frac{1}{2 \Delta \zeta}+\frac{21}{\phi}\right) \vec{r}^{m}(\psi, \zeta)+\frac{3}{\phi} \vec{r}^{m}\left(\psi-\Delta \psi_{i-1}, \zeta+\Delta \zeta\right)+\frac{3}{\phi} \vec{r}^{m}\left(\psi-\Delta \psi_{i-1}, \zeta\right) \\
\left.-\frac{1}{\phi} \vec{r}^{m}\left(\psi-\Delta \psi_{i-1}-\Delta \psi_{i-2}, \zeta+\Delta \zeta\right)-\frac{1}{\phi} \vec{r}^{m}\left(\psi-\Delta \psi_{i-1}-\Delta \psi_{i-2}, \zeta\right)\right\}\left\{\frac{1}{2 \Delta \zeta}+\frac{23}{\phi}\right\}^{-1}
\end{array}

and
\begin{aligned}
\vec{V}=& 4 V_{\infty}+V_{i n d}\left(\vec{r}^{m-1}(\psi, \zeta)\right)+V_{i n d}\left(\vec{r}^{m-1}(\psi+\Delta \psi, \zeta)\right) \\
&+V_{i n d}\left(\vec{r}^{m-1}(\psi, \zeta+\Delta \zeta)\right)+V_{i n d}\left(\vec{r}^{m-1}(\psi+\Delta \psi, \zeta+\Delta \zeta)\right) \\
\phi=& 46 \Delta \psi_{i}+4 \Delta \psi_{i-1}-2 \Delta \psi_{i-2}
\end{aligned}

V_ind has to be computed by integrating the Bio-Savart equation:
$d \vec{V}_{k}=F_{\nu} \frac{\Gamma}{4 \pi} \frac{d \vec{l} \times \vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^{3}}$

$\Gamma$ is a constant value referring to circulation and $F_{\nu}$ is a correction factor preventing singularity.

$F_{\nu}=\frac{|\vec{r}|^{2}}{\left(|\vec{r}|^{2 n}+r_{c}^{2 n}\right)^{1 / n}}$, n is usually taken to be 2 and $r_{c}$ is a generic core radius (meters).

Could someone give me some guidance on how I can solve for $r$ ins the original PDE by writing code in Python or in MATLAB? Also, since $\psi$ is a function of time, is this an initial boundary value problem or just a regular boundary value problem?

Comment: Can you please link the doi of the publication you are reading? I think for those not familiar with the equation it is easier to help seeing the original equations before any numerical scheme is applied, e.g. $\vec{V}$.